# Log management script: A front end for my Json formatted log file?

Tags: json, logging

I am quite new to software dev, but got my first app running. I am generating a lots of log (in .log format, split on 4 levels), my logs are saved in format Json (see here some exemple: https://instabot-cvs.herokuapp.com/log/)

I am not sure if what I am looking for exist: ideally a piece of code (JS based would be best) hosted on my server (Heroku), which would take my .log as an input, and offer my a nice Frontend with filtering and analysis possibilities? And open sources :)?

Am I dreaming, or does this exist? My several attempt a googling such a solution were so far unsuccessful ...

I would be thanksful for any help/tips/explainations.
Clément

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many services that do what you ask for, a few popular open source projects are "logstash" or "graylog", however these are very big and robust, not a small piece of JS you can run on your heroku server.

However a quick google search shows that there are many log-related Heroku add-ons, like this one

https://elements.heroku.com/addons/logentries

Might be worth to check it out

Comment: I never think of those heroku addons! It's a brilliant idea! Thanks a million!